# DITA DTD constraint for table and figure

Tags: dtd, dita

Can anyone help me create DITA DTD constraints?

I want to create Constraints for figure, image and table. 
Image tag with alt tag mandatroy 
I want the figure title to also be mandatory, while table title, desc, and thead with at least one entry.

Answer (score 1):

Create `imageConstraints.mod`:

```
<!ENTITY altReq-constraint 
  "(topic altReq-c)">

<!ENTITY % image.content
                       "((%alt;),
                         (%longdescref;)?)">
```

Then include it into your shell DTD with something like

```
<!ENTITY % altReq-c-def  
  PUBLIC "-//FOO//ELEMENTS DITA 1.2 Required Alt Constraint//EN" 
  "imageConstraint.mod">
%altReq-c-def;
```

and add it the `included-domains` entity

```
<!ENTITY included-domains "...
                           &altReq-constraints;">
```

Figure and table follow the same pattern.

You can't force the at least one table header entry rule with DTDs, for that you need to use e.g. Schematron.

Comment: Thank!..i am getting some complication in figure and table constraints. In figure and table several othere elements are there. do i need to declare all elements and entity in constraints?

Comment: Yes, you need to add the elements you want into `fig` and `table`, there is no shortcut to just make them mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

My DTD knowledge is a bit rusty, but I believe if you are modifying the DTD and the element is optional it will have a question mark next to it

```
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA )>
<!ELEMENT figure (title?) >
```

To make is `title` required, remove the `?`:

```
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA )>
<!ELEMENT figure (title) >
```